# mysqldump into file with any error firing off a cURL request with error information

Tags: command-line, pipe, stderr

I'm attempting to setup a backup that I want to execute from the command line where, in the case of an error, it curls the error to an API endpoint. Something like:

```
mysqldump -u whatever -pwhatever somedb > somebackupfile.sql || curl (..options..) -d $'{error:<ERROR FROM FIRST COMMAND>}'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In what form are you expecting to send the error? As a string _describing_ the error, the actual error message produced on standard error, or simply as the exit status of the previous command?

Comment: @Kusalananda I would expect a string like ```mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'whatever'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the error stream to a separate file and "`curl` it" if there is an error. Then delete it (or keep it, it may be useful?):

```sh
if ! mysqldump -u whatever -pwhatever somedb >somebackupfile.sql 2>error.log
then
    json=$( jq -c -n --arg message "$(cat error.log)" '{ error: $message }' )
    curl ...options... -d "$json"
fi
rm -f error.log   # or not
```

This additionally uses `jq` to properly encode the error output in `error.log` as a JSON text string.

If you want to change the logic so that you send the contents of the `error.log` file whenever it's not empty, maybe because the `mysqldump` program doesn't return a sane exit status (I don't know how this particular program behaves at the moment):

```sh
mysqldump -u whatever -pwhatever somedb >somebackupfile.sql 2>error.log

if [ -s error.log ]; then
    json=$( jq -c -n --arg message "$(cat error.log)" '{ error: $message }' )
    curl ...options... -d "$json"
fi
rm -f error.log   # or not
```

The `-s` file test is *true* if the named file has non-zero size.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to avoid the file but this ended up working for us. Thanks @Kusalananda!